# Encrypt Issue with AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

I have to encrypt data with AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding. I have attached both my Java and Swift code which are working. For swift, i have used the "SCrypto" pod. But now, in order to use this same logic in my Obj C project, i have used the following ObjC code. But it returns a diff value.

Java Code:(WORKING)

```
public String encryption(String unencryptedString) {
    if (unencryptedString == null) {
        return "";
    }
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(SECRET_KEY.getBytes("utf-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 16);
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = unencryptedString.getBytes("utf-8");
        byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(buf));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Swift Code:(WORKING)

```
class func MD5Encryption(stringToBeEncrypted: String) -> String
{
    print("stringToBeEncrypted..\(stringToBeEncrypted)")

    let plaintext = stringToBeEncrypted.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

    let digestKey = "##SECRETKEY##"
    let sharedSecretKey = digestKey.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!.MD5() // AES-256

    let ciphertext = try! plaintext.encrypt(.aes, options: [.PKCS7Padding, .ECBMode], key: sharedSecretKey)
    let encryptedString = ciphertext.base64EncodedString()

    return encryptedString
}
```

But in the following ObjC code, it gives a different encrypted String.

```
- (void) generateHeader
{
    NSString *stringToBeEncyrpted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@", userId, contactName];
    NSData *plainData = [stringToBeEncyrpted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData * cipherText = [plainData AES256Operation:kCCEncrypt key:@"##SECRETKEY##" iv:nil];
    NSString *encyrptedString = [cipherText base64Encoding];
    NSLog(@"encyrptedString..%@", encyrptedString);
}

- (NSData *)AES256Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
        char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
        bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
        key = [key stringFromMD5];
        // fetch key data
        [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

        //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
        //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
        //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
        size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
        void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

        size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
        CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                      keyPtr, kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);

        if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
            return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
        }
        free(buffer);
        return nil;
}
```

My key requirements are:
1) First I need to apply the MD5 algorithm on the secret key
2) Then i need to encrypt the 'stringToBeEncrypted' with the AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding

This is because it is how it is decrypted in the API end.

Comment: Please edit in the input / output (key, plaintext, ciphertext) so we don't have to compile the partial code to see what's wrong. Hexadecimals are strongly preferred.

Comment: PS you are confusing key and block size in your objective C call to `CCCrypt`.